# Returning values from a client coded in java?

Tags: java, client, return, desktop

I was wondering if it is possible to return values from a desktop-application client that is coded in Java? If so if anyone could point me in the right direction or at some articles I could read. I'm experienced with Java and other languages just never have wondered about this and it would make for a really interesting personal project.

Comment: What do you mean "return variables"?

Comment: Please update your question with an example.

Comment: Better elaborate a bit. Put things on the clipboard (?), allow drag (of some app element) and drop. Open browser with geneated HTML, open generated document with system assigned app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "set the process exit code" then yes,

```
System.exit(2);
```

will return an exit status of 2.